# Laravel API for all user types

Tags: php, laravel, api, web-services, jwt

The question is pretty straight forward but honestly speaking, i found many answers but none of them satisfied me. 
I have developed APIs for Mobile application in Laravel. I am using tymon/JWT Auth 0.5 for accessing web services.

I also want to use the same API for the dashboard user/admin, what is the best practice in this scenario?

Possible solutions:

1. Using same API methods with but different routes and controllers for
   web.
2. Same API and routes but how?

Comment: You can use the same API methods with different routes defined in `web.php` file. Just change the web routes and use the same APIs!

Comment: But that api are protected with jwt.auth middleware which checks for the token, and if i use web.php then i will not be able to access it through web.

Comment: If you want to use jwt auth token from web side also, use it as it is, else copy all codes and paste it to created new web controllers with removing token code. This is only the way to use it. OR you can remove middleware from web routes!

Comment: For your information i am using repository structure, and rewriting the code is not a good idea for web.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the possible solution of first.
In laravel it was provided a Api.php in routes folder for API. so you can made your api routes there.